# Cisco 2950 Express Setup

Tags: cisco, switch

I've been donated a Cisco Catalyst 2950 Switch by the company I work for to have a play with.

I've reset it back to Factory Defaults, but having an issue with getting to Express Setup.

I've followed the Express Setup (And Factory Reset) guide as listed here: [Catalyst 2950 Switch Getting Started Guide](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2950/hardware/quick/guide/2950gsg2.html#wp49930)

Everything goes fine, until I get to step 10, I enter 10.0.0.1 into the browser, but I just get a Error 324 response.

ServerFault wouldn't let me post a picture, so here is a link to the browser screenshot: [image: Browser Screenshot]

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what this may be?

Comment: How about just hooking up a serial port and setting it up from the console?  If you're trying to learn, this is the way to do it.

Comment: I just want to second what @rnxrx said, you will very rarely if ever find that level of switch even running the web server, console up and learn the cli it will serve you much better

Comment: That was the original intention, to use console, however the adapter is in the office, and was hoping to have a play over the weekend. Thanks though!

Comment: The RJ45 -> DB9 connector is pretty simple to hack together.  The pinouts are at http://www.allpinouts.org/index.php/Cisco_Console_RJ45_to_DB9_Pin - you may find you have cables around you can make work.